# when changing country, then display state and city to place holder value

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am having Country, state and city . first time I have selected Country, state and city. When I change different country, **I am expecting to display default value like select state , select city**. after selecting country again I need to select different state and city under changed country. Please help me to **display default value on state and city after changing Country**.

step 1) select country

step 2) select State

step 3) select City

[image]

step 4) change country
[image]

step 5) expecting after changing country expecting state and city should change to default value(--select State--) (--Select City --)

actual:- It displaying displacement state and city value.

my code : -

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch,useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { Button, Form, message, Select, Row, Col, Alert} from 'antd';
import { DeleteOutlined } from "@ant-design/icons";
import { Country, State, City }  from 'country-state-city';
import { SetStudentInfo } from "../../../../../redux/reducer/StudentRegister/StudentReg.actions";

const { Option } = Select;
const Countries = Country.getAllCountries()
const States = State.getAllStates()
const Cities = City.getAllCities()

export default (props) => {
  const studentInfo = useSelector((state) => state.studentInfo)
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const [form] = Form.useForm()
  const [error, setError] = useState("")
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
  const [collegesList, setCollegesList] = useState(props.collegesList)
  const [collegesSelectedList, setCollegesSelectedList] = useState(studentInfo ? studentInfo.institutesList ? studentInfo.institutesList : [] : [])
  const [selectedCountry, setSelectedCountry] = useState(studentInfo ? studentInfo.country : null)
  const [selectedState, setSelectedState] = useState(studentInfo ? studentInfo.state : null)
  const [selectedCity, setSelectedCity] = useState(studentInfo ? studentInfo.city : null)
  const [filteredState, setFilteredState] = useState(States)
  const [filteredCity, setFilteredCity] = useState(Cities)
  const [warning, setWarning] = useState()
  let count = 1
  let checkDuplicateSelect = false
  
  const handleSubmit = () => {
    let formData = {
      country: selectedCountry ? selectedCountry : '',
      state: selectedState ? selectedState : '',
      city: selectedCity ? selectedCity : '',
      institutesList: collegesSelectedList ? collegesSelectedList : []
    }
    setError("");
    setLoading(true)

    console.log('formData: ', formData)
    dispatch(SetStudentInfo(formData));
    props.nextPage(true)
  }

  const handleRemoveList = (college) => {
    setCollegesSelectedList(collegesSelectedList.filter((c) => c !== college))
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const defaultState = {
      name: "--select--"
    };
    setFilteredState([defaultState,...filteredState])
    setFilteredCity([defaultState,...filteredCity])
  }, []);
  
  return (
      <div className="form-width">
        <Form form={form} onFinish={handleSubmit} layout="vertical" className="content">
          <h3 style={{textAlign: "center", fontWeight: "lighter"}}>Step 1 of 2</h3>
          <Row>
            <Col span={11}>
              <h3 >I want to go to</h3>
            </Col>
            <Col span={2}></Col>
            <Col span={11}>
              <h3 >I want to study at the <br />following universities &#38; colleges</h3>
            </Col>
          </Row>
          <Row>
              <Col span={11} style={{marginTop: "3%"}}>
                <Form.Item
                    name="cntry"
                    label="Country"
                    initialValue={studentInfo ? studentInfo.country : null}
                    rules={[
                    {
                        required: true,
                        message: "Please choose the country you wanted to go.",
                    },
                    ]}
                >
                    <Select
                    showSearch
                    placeholder="Select country"
                    loading={loading}
                    onChange={(code) => {
                      setSelectedCountry(Countries[code].name)
                      setFilteredState(States.filter((state) => state.countryCode === Countries[code].isoCode ))
                    }}
                    optionFilterProp="children"
                    filterOption={(input, option) =>
                        option.children.toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) >= 0
                    }
                    >
                    {Object.keys(Countries).map((code) => (
                        <Option value={code}>{Countries[code].name}</Option>
                    ))}
                    </Select>
                </Form.Item>

                <Form.Item
                    name="prvc"
                    label="Province"
                    initialValue={studentInfo ? studentInfo.state ? studentInfo.state : null : null}
                >
                    <Select
                    showSearch
                    loading={loading}
                    placeholder="Select Province"
                    onChange={(code) => {
                      setSelectedState(States[code].name)
                      setFilteredCity(Cities.filter((city) => city.countryCode === filteredState[code].countryCode && city.stateCode === filteredState[code].isoCode))
                      }}
                    optionFilterProp="children"
                    filterOption={(input, option) =>
                        option.children.toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) >= 0
                    }
                    >
                    {Object.keys(filteredState).map((state) => (
                        <Option value={state}>{filteredState[state].name}</Option>
                    ))}
                    </Select>
                </Form.Item>

                <Form.Item
                    name="cty"
                    label="City"
                    initialValue={studentInfo ? studentInfo.city ? studentInfo.city : null : null}
                >
                    <Select
                    showSearch
                    loading={loading}
                    placeholder="Select City"
                    onChange={(code) => {
                      setSelectedCity(Cities[code].name)
                    }}
                    optionFilterProp="children"
                    filterOption={(input, option) =>
                        option.children.toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) >= 0
                    }
                    >
                    {Object.keys(filteredCity).map((city) => (
                        <Option value={city}>{filteredCity[city].name}</Option>
                    ))}
                    </Select>
                </Form.Item>
              </Col>
              <div style={{border: "1px solid #a8f0d9", margin: "2% 2% 2% 2%"}}></div>
              <Col span={11} style={{marginTop: "3%"}}>
                
                <Form.Item
                    name="insts"
                    label="Type institute name here"
                >
                    <Select
                    showSearch
                    loading={loading}
                    placeholder="Select Colleges"
                    onChange={(college) => {
                      checkDuplicateSelect = collegesSelectedList.some(c => c === (collegesList[college].name))
                      if (!checkDuplicateSelect && count <= 10) {
                        setCollegesSelectedList([...collegesSelectedList, collegesList[college].name])
                      } else if (!checkDuplicateSelect && count > 10) {
                        setWarning("Max no.of institues[10] list exceeded.")
                         
                      } else if (checkDuplicateSelect) {
                        setWarning("Already this institute selected.")
                      }
                    }}
                    optionFilterProp="children"
                    filterOption={(input, option) =>
                        option.children.toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) >= 0
                    }
                    >
                    {Object.keys(collegesList).map((college) => (
                        <Option value={college}>{collegesList[college].name}</Option>
                    ))}
                    </Select>
                </Form.Item>
                {warning && <Alert message={warning} type="warning" showIcon />}
                <label>List of institutes selected</label>
                <div style={{ border: "1px solid #b3e2d2", height: "19vh", overflowY: "auto" }}>
                  <Form.Item>
                    {collegesSelectedList.map((college) => (
                      <ul style={{listStyleType: "none", padding: "0px"}}>
                        <li key={college} >
                          {count++}.{college}<Button size="small" onClick={() => handleRemoveList(college)} icon={<DeleteOutlined />} danger />
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                      ))
                    }
                  </Form.Item>
                </div>
              </Col>
          </Row>
          <Form.Item style={{textAlign: "center", marginTop: "2%"}}>
            <Button htmlType="submit"  
                    type="primary"                       
                    loading={loading}
                    disabled={loading}>
              Next
            </Button>
          </Form.Item>
        </Form>
      </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Your inputs don't appear to be controlled inputs. If you want to programmatically set their value then they need to be fully controlled inputs. You could also use a React key to "reset" the inputs. You seem to have not included a complete, reproducible code example (I couldn't reproduce your code in a running codesandbox). Can you provide a more complete and comprehensive code example?

Answer (score 1):

the Form api `initialValues` only works when **Set value by Form initialization or reset**, so does the Form.Item.

```
<Form.Item
  name="prvc"
  label="Province"
  initialValue={studentInfo ? studentInfo.state ? studentInfo.state : null : null}
>
```

you change the initialValue after initialization won't work. you can use the `FormInstance` api `form.setFieldsValue({prvc: 'the value you want to set', cty: 'the value you want to set'})`. like below:

```
<Form.Item
  name="cntry"
  label="Country"
  initialValue={studentInfo ? studentInfo.country : null}
  rules={[
    {
       required: true,
       message: "Please choose the country you wanted to go.",
     },
  ]}
>
  <Select
     showSearch
     placeholder="Select country"
     loading={loading}
     onChange={(code) => {
       // setSelectedCountry(Countries[code].name)
       // setFilteredState(States.filter((state) => state.countryCode === Countries[code].isoCode ))
       // form is const [form] = Form.useForm()
       form.setFieldsValue({
         prvc: ...,
         cty: ...
       })
     }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if what you want to do is only about displaying a **defaultValue**, you can add that prop to your select. You can do something like this:

```
<Select defaultValue="Select state" style={{ width: 120 }}>
      <Option value="anycity">anycity</Option>
</Select>
```

That would always mantain the default value before select the state or city

Comment: I'm fairly certain that OP wants the state and city inputs to "reset" when the country value is updated. In other words, they want to reset *back* to an "initial value".